# Irreducible representations of the symmetric group in GAP

Tags: representation-theory, gap

I try to find the irreducible representation of the symmetric group (over the complex numbers) in a quick way using GAP.
I made the following program that gives the irreducible representation corresponding to a partition:

```
DeclareOperation("allirredrepsofsymmetricgroup",[IsList]);

InstallMethod(allirredrepsofsymmetricgroup, "for a representation of a quiver", [IsList],0,function(LIST)

local n,U,g,tbl,irr,W,i,WW;

n:=LIST[1];

U:=Partitions(n);g:= SymmetricGroup( n );SetName( g, "Sn" );tbl:= CharacterTable( g );irr:= Irr( g );W:=[];for i in [1..Size(U)] do Append(W,[[U[i],irr[i]]]);od;

WW:=[];for i in W do Append(WW,[[i[1],IrreducibleRepresentationsDixon(g,i[2])]]);od;

return(WW);

end);
```

Example on how to use it in GAP: n:=4;U:=allirredrepsofsymmetricgroup([n]);

Sadly it is very slow and only works for $n \leq 6$.

> Question: Is there a quicker way to obtain all irreducible representations for the symmetric group in GAP that maybe works for $n \leq 12$ or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appended is some rather ad-hoc code (it uses global variables for interim storage...), that (following the textbook by B. Steinberg) calculates a basis for a Specht module, as a submodule of the group algebra. (Alas for left multiplication, never got to fixing it.) It should get you up to degree 10, 12 might be tough.

By acting with left multiplication (transpose to make it proper action) we can get matrices.

For example:

```
gap> s:=specht([3,2,2,1]);;Length(s);
70
gap> b:=Basis(VectorSpace(Rationals,s));;
gap> gens:=GeneratorsOfGroup(symm);
[ (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), (1,2) ]
gap> mats:=List(gens,z->TransposedMat(List(b,x->Coefficients(b,z*x))));;
gap> Length(mats[1]);
70
gap> Size(Group(mats));
40320
```

The code:

````
n:=-1;

alambda:=function(lambda)
local p,a,t,i;
  if n<>Sum(lambda) then
    n:=Sum(lambda);
    symm:=SymmetricGroup(n);
    qg:=GroupRing(Rationals,symm);
    emb:=Embedding(symm,qg);
  fi;
  t:=[];a:=0;
  p:=symm;
  for i in lambda do
    Add(t,[a+1..a+i]);
    p:=Stabilizer(p,t[Length(t)],OnSets);
    a:=a+i;
  od;
  a:=Zero(qg);
  for i in Elements(p) do
    a:=a+ImagesRepresentative(emb,i);
  od;
  return 1/Size(p)*a;
end;

blambda:=function(lambda)
local q,b,t,i,j;
  if n<>Sum(lambda) then
    n:=Sum(lambda);
    symm:=SymmetricGroup(n);
    qg:=GroupRing(Rationals,symm);
    emb:=Embedding(symm,qg);
  fi;
  t:=[];b:=0;
  q:=symm;
  for i in [1..lambda[1]] do
    b:=[i];
    for j in [2..Length(lambda)] do
      if lambda[j]>=i then
        Add(b,b[Length(b)]+lambda[j-1]);
      fi;
    od;
    Add(t,b);
    q:=Stabilizer(q,b,OnSets);
  od;
  b:=Zero(qg);
  for i in Elements(q) do
    b:=b+SignPerm(i)*ImagesRepresentative(emb,i);
  od;
  return 1/Size(q)*b;
end;

specht:=function(lambda)
local c,b,bas,i,g,a,aa,piv,cp,sol;
  c:=alambda(lambda)*blambda(lambda);
  bas:=Basis(qg);
  b:=[c];
  c:=[Coefficients(bas,c)];
  piv:=List(c,PositionNonZero);
  cp:=List(c,x->x{piv});
  i:=1;
  while i<=Length(b) do
    for g in GeneratorsOfLeftOperatorRingWithOne(qg) do
      #Print(i," ",g,"\n");
      a:=g*b[i];
      aa:=Coefficients(bas,a);
      sol:=SolutionMat(cp,aa{piv});
      if sol=fail or sol*c<>aa then
        Add(b,a);
        Add(c,aa);
        TriangulizeMat(c);
        piv:=List(c,PositionNonZero);
        cp:=List(c,x->x{piv});
      fi;
    od;
    i:=i+1;
  od;
  return b;
end;
```
````

Comment: Thank you. After entering your programs and doing some tests some extremely strange things happen. Here an example of what I entered after copy pasting your program into gap:  gap> s:=specht([2,2,1]);;Length(s);
5
gap> n:=2;;symm:=SymmetricGroup(n);P:=Partitions(n);W:=[];for t in P do Append(W,[[t,Size(specht(t))]]);od;W;
Sym( [ 1 .. 2 ] )
[ [ 1, 1 ], [ 2 ] ]
[  ]
[ [ [ 1, 1 ], 60 ], [ [ 2 ], 60 ] ]

Comment: Sorry, it seems hard to format the output in the comments. But the command "specht" seems to give wrong output when used in a "for loop" after using the command "specht" in a specific example (here used in the specific example [2,2,1] first and then a "for loop" for all Partitions of 2 is used but it gives the wrong output then.

Comment: The correct output in the for loop should be [ [ [ 1, 1 ],1 ], [ [ 2 ], 1] ] instead of [ [ [ 1, 1 ], 60 ], [ [ 2 ], 60 ] ] but somehow the command "specht" seems to depend on earlier input and gives wrong results for loops.

Comment: Yes. This is what I meant by "ad-hoc" code using global variables. You use the variables `n` and `symm` that the code also uses, and in particular needs to track information. Use other names.

Comment: Thanks again!!!